# Websites not working with Opera 11.00, major bugs

Tags: opera, javascript

Sites like ebay and even superuser stop working properly when I use opera 11.00.  Menus stop working everywhere from ebay to godaddy.  Hovering on a menu item doesn't expand it, no sub menu slides out.  This makes a large number of very popular websites unusable.  Am I right in assuming this is a javascript issue?

I use opera for the turbo feature (I have tested opera with and without turbo so it's not turbo's fault) because I'm on mobile broadband until I get my phone line sorted out.  Turbo helps me save money, as well as allowing me to surf at a sane speed.  Is there a firefox or chrome equivalent to opera turbo that doesn't cost money?

I'm using Opera 11.00, build 1156.

Answer (score 1):

> Sites like ebay and even superuser stop working properly when I use opera 11.00. Menus stop working everywhere from ebay to godaddy.

Can you be more specific? I cannot reproduce the issues you're describing - the menus slide out just fine. Of course, make sure JavaScript is turned on via Quick Preferences > Enable JavaScript. If you can point me to specific site issues, we can look into them (I work for Opera).

Answer (score 0):

No there is no in-built alternatives, but you can use [Ziproxy](http://ziproxy.sourceforge.net/) for example. You need a host computer to run it and make your browser connect to the Ziproxy as a http proxy. (Just ask a tech-savvy friend who owns a VPS or a server. I did that, had a full-fledged gbps Ziproxy server on a brand, dedicated rack-server.)

If this won't work out, try using Opera 10.xx. You can get older versions [here](http://www.filehippo.com/download_opera/). Just install the latest one. Back then, I've been using version 9.xx without any problem. Ever since they rushed out the 10th series, Opera's been REALLY , REALLY buggy. I mean.. REALLY.

(I can run a Ziproxy for you maybe. Depends on how much do you surf the web. :))